# electric cable below deck without piping

Tags: electrical

i have a contractor who fixed my outdoor lighting. he had the electric wire in a piping. However, when i moved one of the deck slats, i found that the wire was not in the piping below the deck. Is this normal?
btw: i live in toronto and the weather drips below -20 degree C in winter
[image]

Comment: The sharp edge of the pipe not good, should at least have an elbow.

Comment: Is that cable rated for outdoor or underground use?  Is the cable exposed to sunlight anywhere under the deck?  Is the underside of the deck used for storage or used at all by people?

Comment: it is on the underside of the deck. there is nothing stored below the deck.

Answer (score 2):

This is OK. It has nothing to do with the temperature. The pipe (conduit) is just to protect the cable against mechanical damage. Since there is no access in that area, it does not have to be protected.

In the US, it is customary to put an elbow at the end so that the cable does not rub against the plastic edge. Elsewhere in the world (esp. Germany, where I live part-time), there is no elbow.

Comment: Bzzt! Wrong! The pictured cable (type NM or NM-B) is not allowed outdoors. This installation is not legal.

Comment: The question was regarding the conduit. But if it's NM or NM-B it is forbidden outside. If it's UF-B it's OK outside.

Comment: Correct answer +1

Comment: so, if i get my contractor to put a conduit just like in the picture, would it make it better?

Comment: @junkone First, figure out what type of cable you have there. It should have markings on the side. The correct type is dark gray.

Comment: It certainly *looks* like 14ga NM, but color can be difficult in photos, so it's possible it could be UF.